# How can I copy files recursively without overwriting duplicate file names?

Tags: bash, shell, find, rename, cp

Let's say I have files nested in subdirectories with potentially duplicate file names. I want to copy all files to a new directory but prevent overwriting AND preserve filenames (mostly).

The following **does not** work because it overwrites duplicate filenames:

```
find /SourceDir/. -type f -exec cp -pv \{\} /DestDir/ \;
```

Adding `noclobber` (`cp -n`) doesn't help either because duplicates are just skipped.

**Current File Structure:**

```
SourceDir
--SubdirA
----File1.gif
---- ...
----File1000.jpg
--SubdirB
----File1.gif
---- ...
----File1000.png
...
--SubdirZ
----SubdirAA
------File1.sh
------ ...
------File1000.jpg
```

**Desired File Structure:**

```
DestDir
--File1.gif
--File1_1.gif   <-- original name was `File1.gif` but this already existed
--File2.jpg
--File2.gif     <-- `File2.jpg` already exists, but not `File2.gif`
--File3.gif
--File3_1.gif
--File4.jpg
--File4_1.jpg
--File4_2.jpg   <-- original name was `File4.jpg`, but `File4_1.jpg` already existed too.
-- ...
--File1000.png
```

I **do not** want to rename every file. And I don't want to give arbitrary hashes to those I need to duplicate. What do you recommend?

I'm on a Mac, so Linux commands are all fair game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

SourceDir=".";
DestDir="../dest";

cd ${SourceDir}
find .  -type f |
while read x
do
  bn=`basename $x`;
  if [ -f "${DestDir}/$bn" ]
  then
    for i in {1..9999}
    do
        if [ ! -f "${DestDir}/${bn%.*}_${i}.${bn##*.}" ]
        then
            echo "Next free file extension is no $i";
            bn="${DestDir}/${bn%.*}_${i}.${bn##*.}"
            break;
        fi
    done
  fi
  echo "copy file $x to ${DestDir}/$bn";
  cp -p "$x" "${DestDir}/$bn";
 done
```

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. The `if [ ! -f ../dest/$bn ]` line returns `too many arguments`. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: did you mean the find command. you can change the first line to **find SourceDir -name *.gif -type f |** to get only gif files

Comment: Also, how does this handle duplicate names? I don't see where duplicates are appended a `_1` (where `file.jpg` becomes `file_1.jpg` if `file.jpg` already exists).

Comment: sorry, i will change it , so that it also copy duplicates

Comment: Re: did you mean the find command...  I have your script above saved as a shell script. It returns `./img-cp.sh: line 7: [: too many arguments`. And line 7 (in my script) is `if [ ! -f ../dest/$bn ]`. It could be referencing an earlier problem but I'm not proficient enough in shell to know where to look.

Comment: @Ryan , if have change my Answer. so it extend the filename file_[1..9999] if a file exists

Comment: Looks good, except I still get "too many arguments" at the same place. I think name-based exclusions, and running it more than once could create even more duplicates. Can you suggest an alternative to your `if [ ! -f ...` line?

Comment: change thise line **if [ -f ${DestDir}/$bn ]** to **if [ -f "${DestDir}/$bn" ]**. So is it possible that you have file with a space in the filename

Comment: That's it. I'm getting similar errors on `cp` usage for copy as well. Can you change everywhere to allow spaces in file names?

Comment: yes, it only (i hope) one line more to change **cp -p "$x" "${DestDir}/$bn";** . I have change both lines in my Answer

Comment: Thanks so much! Great answer. I hope it is useful to others as well.